# DAX lookupvalue from calculated table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to add a column in a table containing the minimum value of a group of another table.

I have a `Table A` with unique IDs.

[image]

In this table I would need to add a column `min_value` containing the minimum value for each ID in another table `Table B` :

[image]

I know I could use `SUMMARIZE()` on my `Table B` in order to create a calculated table with the minimum value of each ID, save this `Table C` and then use `LOOKUPVALUE()` between my `Table A` and `Table C` to get the column I need in `Table A`.
But I don't want to save this `Table C` because it would not be used again, and I did not find a way to use the result of my `SUMMARIZE()` directly in my `LOOKUPVALUE()` without saving the calculated table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to provide sample data in table format here.

There are quite a few ways to achieve what you want  depending on what is the relationship between these two tables and whether you want a calculated column or measure.

**`Calculated Column - with relationship between 'Table A'[ID] and 'Table B'[ID]`**

```
ALLEXCEPT = --can be utilized as a measure too
CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Table B'[Value] ), ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table A', 'Table A'[ID] ) )

RELATEDTABLE =
    MINX ( RELATEDTABLE ( 'Table B' ), 'Table B'[Value] )
    
IN =
CALCULATE (
    MINX ( 'Table B', 'Table B'[Value] ),
    'Table A'[ID] IN VALUES ( 'Table B'[ID] )
)
```

**`Calculated Column - with no relationship between 'Table A' and 'Table B'`**

```
TREATAS =
CALCULATE (
    CALCULATE (
        MINX ( 'Table B', 'Table B'[Value] ),
        TREATAS ( VALUES ( 'Table A'[ID] ), 'Table B'[ID] )
    )
)
```

**`Measure - with relationship between 'Table A'[ID] and 'Table B'[ID]`**

```
_in =
CALCULATE (
    MIN ( 'Table B'[Value] ),
    'Table A'[ID] IN VALUES ( 'Table B'[ID] )
)
```

**`Measure - with no relationship between 'Table A' and 'Table B'`**

```
_treatas =
CALCULATE (
    MIN ( 'Table B'[Value] ),
    TREATAS ( VALUES ( 'Table A'[ID] ), 'Table B'[id] )
)
```

Comment: Thank you smpa01 for your thorough response ! It helps a lot. I'm new to the PowerBI / DAX world and even thouth I thought my question was precise, your answer makes me realize that I forgot a lot of context information

Comment: Could you please explain why we need 2 CALCULATE() in the 2nd solution ? (calculated column - no relationship)

Comment: The 2nd CALCULATE converts row context to filter context which also known as [Context Transition](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-context-transition/)